# How to split and organize the data in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Below is a sample data from the input file.

```
File Id: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\, chk\czzjrt
jee_only = chk\zz9ycd, chk\hz659l
year_on = chk\dytg6
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@jee_only = r

[/Release]
year_on = r

[/Redmine/Treehub]
@div = r
@jee_only = rw
```

I want it to be organized like below to an output file

```
Name            group          id           folder             access
456_Milo_123    met         chk\rel_io_chk    /                 rw
456_Milo_123    met         chk\dev_op_io     /                 rw
456_Milo_123    div         chk\kzhr2x        /                 rw  
456_Milo_123    div         chk\czzjrt        /                 rw
456_Milo_123    div         chk\zz52t0        /                 rw
456_Milo_123    jee_only    chk\zz9ycd        /                 rw
456_Milo_123    jee_only    chk\zz9ycd        /                 rw
456_Milo_123    year_on     chk\dytg6         /Release          r
456_Milo_123    div         chk\czzjrt        /Redmine/Treehub  r
456_Milo_123    div         chk\zz52t0        /Redmine/Treehub  r
456_Milo_123    jee_only    chk\zz9ycd        /Redmine/Treehub  rw
456_Milo_123    jee_only    chk\zz9ycd        /Redmine/Treehub  rw
```

I have tried many combinations of split and splice to organize it but not able to achieve the above output.

My incomplete tries

```
file = File.open("input.txt", "rb")
values = file.read.split("File Id:")
values.each do |val|
  val.reject {||a| a.match(/^#|^\[/m)}
    end
#not sure how to process further    
match_by_id("input.txt") do |id, lines|
  lines.each do |line|
    group, group_values = line.split("=")
    group.reject {|a| a.match(/^#|^\[/m)}
    end
#not sure how to process further    
end
values.shift
```

Any idea how to do that ? Thanks.

**Input file**

```
File Id: C:/my_files/00_Roll_Tom-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Random as on 12/19/2016
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io,
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\zz52t0, chk\czzjrt
rakeonly = chk\rzgnsd, chk\cztw5h

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
*******************************************************************************************
File Id: C:/my_files/Rander-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st QA
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\541kmj, chk\zz52t0
app_only = chk\zz9ycd
check_io = chk\wder4, chk\zz9ycd
div_write = chk\lo98j3
year_on = chk\3w345f
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@app_only= r
@check_io = r
@div_write = rw
@year_on = r

[/wedmin]
@check_io = rw
@div_write= rw

[/doc/prod]
@div = rw
@app_only = r
@year_on = rw
*******************************************************************************************
File Id: C:/my_files/456_Milo_123-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Jan 21st Prod
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io
div = chk\kzhr2x, chk\, chk\czzjrt
jee_only = chk\zz9ycd, chk\hz659l
year_on = chk\dytg6
[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@jee_only = r

[/Release]
@year_on = r

[/Redmine/Treehub]
@div = r
@jee_only = rw
******************************************************************************************
File Id: C:/my_files/Docker_red-values.txt

#RakeBoss-Check it io.
[groups]
met = chk\rel_io_chk, chk\dev_op_io, chk\njk987
div = chk\gzlqvg, chk\zzkgyp, chk\lzg0rp, chk\gzp2kv
rakeonly = chk\qzvjq0, chk\kz6w6t, chk\bzy4kj, chk\dzfbhp

[/]
@met = rw
@div = rw
@rakeonly = r
******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: can u pls attach the input file?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Thanks for looking into it, I don't find any option to attach the file, so have edited the question and pasted the input content.

Comment: is there any reason why year_on doesn't have an @ symbol?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Sincere apologies, that was an editing mistake. I have corrected it in the question. Thanks. Year_in should have @ symbol

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Any chance you had a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : Really appreciate you taking time to look into my issue. Thank you. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputations to place a bounty. I was trying from my end, but not sure how to move forward. I shall wait for your guidance.

Comment: i can't guarantee a response ~3% chance i can get around to it - so don't hold your breath, i threw away my notes on this problem anyways; if i do it will be very, very general answers so you will know HOW to solve it. chrs.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon : got it!

Comment: congratulations! all the best

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with splitting by blocks.

```
file = File.open("input.txt", "rb")
blocks = file.read.split(/\n\s*\n/)
```

and each block need different treatment...

```
name = parse_name blocks[0]
groups = parse_groups blocks[1]
....
```

parse_groups idea is to get block inside of `[groups]` and `[/]` and parse it like `split(/^([^\s]+)\s*=\s*([^,\s])/)`...